# I have a array which is dynamic like Array ( [122] => 2 [123] => 3 [124] => 6 ) and I want to fetch record from the database via these array value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

My project is all about tradesman and customer where customer post their job choose location and the tradesman can find the job of his area but the condition is tradesman can add multiple area So the Question is there is a tradesman whose added three location which is like

```
$locs=Array ( [122] => 2 [123] => 3 [124] => 6 )
```

I wanted to fetch records from the database where these location ID available 2,3,6

what will be the Query

```sql
SELECT j.*, l.location_name, c.customer_name, c.customer_status, s.service_title 
FROM ".TABLE_JOB."  AS j 
LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_LOCATION." AS l ON (l.location_id=j.location_id) 
LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_CUSTOMER." AS c ON (c.customer_id=j.customer_id) 
LEFT JOIN ".TABLE_SERVICE." AS s ON (s.service_id=j.service_id) 
WHERE j.status='PENDING' 
  AND c.customer_status='ACTIVATED' 
  AND j.location_id='".$locs."'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `implode()` function to convert array into string and then `in` in mysql query.

```
$locsIds = implode(',', $locs);
select j.*, l.location_name, c.customer_name, c.customer_status, s.service_title from ".TABLE_JOB." as j left join ".TABLE_LOCATION." as l on (l.location_id=j.location_id) left join ".TABLE_CUSTOMER." as c on (c.customer_id=j.customer_id) left join ".TABLE_SERVICE." as s on(s.service_id=j.service_id) where j.status='PENDING' AND c.customer_status='ACTIVATED' and j.location_id IN ({$locsIds})
```

Comment: Happy to help you. Green Tick ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code.

```
$location = '';

foreach($locs as $key=>$value){
 $location .= $value.","; 
}

$location = rtrim($location,",");

select j.*, l.location_name, c.customer_name, c.customer_status, s.service_title from ".TABLE_JOB." as j left join ".TABLE_LOCATION." as l on (l.location_id=j.location_id) left join ".TABLE_CUSTOMER." as c on (c.customer_id=j.customer_id) left join ".TABLE_SERVICE." as s on(s.service_id=j.service_id) where j.status='PENDING' AND c.customer_status='ACTIVATED' and j.location_id IN ($location);
```

This way you will get all the records with location_id in  2,3,6 .

Hope it helps.

Comment: Welcome. Please mark the answer as approved if it helped. @madhukanttiwari